# What is the alternatives safely keep files in android app?

Tags: java, android, encryption

my app download files from server into app. There could be lots of those file. One file is about 100 mb. I need to do something to safely keep them into my app.

Thirst i tried to encrypt files. How ever this is bad solution because to encrypt and decrypt 100 mb file (it's pdf file) take a some time. Also i need at a time to read this file so i need to decrypt and write decrypted file into some other file for reading at this time files is reachable. 
Furthermore i can't keep this file in memory, because of file size. So maybe there is the way to encrypt directory in internal storage where file is saved ? Or this is not good idea as i should then encrypt every file in directory.

As my files is pdf, i could put password to int, but then how to do this ? Also i could try to check if device is rooted or not, but i think someone would find workaround.

So what would you suggest ?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by encrypting? PDFs generally can't be edited so you don't have to worry about data consistency. I assume you're displaying the pdfs at some stage, so I'm not sure privacy is your concern either.

Comment: I don't want to that user could copy pdf into other device or pc, where he could read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have 3 options: to encrypt your data; to store the pdfs in a private folder; or to not store the files on-device.

**1) Encrypt your data:** As you've said, there are disadvantages because the pdfs are quite big and if you can't have those stored in memory, you need to write the decrypted files to file anyway before displaying them, so this doesn't really solve your problem.

**2) Store the pdfs in a private folder:** Alternatively you could store the pdfs in a private folder only accessible through your app. This can be done using

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

as noted [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal). "`MODE_PRIVATE` will create the file (or replace a file of the same name) and make it private to your application". The only problem I see with this is if people are using rooted phones and can access your app's private folders. The only way around this (as far as I know) is to use option 3.

**3) Don't store the files on device:** You could download the data, or parts of it, each time. This will guarantee that people can't copy the files because they never persist on the device. You could use Google Docs to stream only portions of the document to reduce download requirements if you want. The problem with this is the huge data requirement.

I think you need to weigh up the pros and cons and decide which is best for you. I'd personally go with option 2. I don't think you'll find a solution that addresses all the problems.

Comment: I had done till now that i store pdf in private folders. Maybe there is possibility to check whether device is rooted or not.

Comment: How serious is it if people get your files? It is impossible to stop people copying your files if they really want to. They could packet sniff the HTTP packets as you download the file and store it themselves if they really want to. You need to balance risk and effort. I'm not sure if you can detect if a device is rooted or not, but if people want your files badly enough, they will get them.

Comment: Well i am using certificates with communication with server so it's secure. Well i have an idea to put a password for pdf as i see just this solution. Thank you for help i would accept your answer, this is useful

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate it. Even if you download the files securely, which is definitely possible, people can use the screenshot function on their Android device to capture any information you display to them. Just a thought.